# jQuery ui-sortable open original place holder on drag outside of list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable vertical single column list. What I need:

1) Open original placeholder where the element was on start when user drags an element outside of the list. I need it to prevent drop outside of list. Is it possible?

2) Is it possible to add or change tolerance option? I need to setup reordering (for vertical list) when top border of dragging element overlaps bottom border of list elements. I managed get this while dragginf upward but when you dragginf down sorting work on mouse overlap.

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    sort: function (event, ui) {
        var list = $(this),
            w = ui.helper.outerWidth(),
            h = ui.helper.outerHeight();

        list.children().each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('ui-sortable-helper') || $(this).hasClass('ui-sortable-placeholder')) {
                return true;
            }

            var currElementHeight = $(this).outerHeight(),
                overlap = $(this).position().top + currElementHeight - ui.position.top,
                placeBefore = ui.position.top > $(this).position().top;

            if (overlap > 0 && overlap < currElementHeight) {
                if (placeBefore)
                    $('.ui-sortable-placeholder', list).insertBefore($(this));
                else
                    $('.ui-sortable-placeholder', list).insertAfter($(this));
                return false;
            }

            if ($(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth() < ui.position.left) {
                console.log('out');
                //ui.item.parent().sortable('cancel');
            }

        });

    },
});
```

Here is my experiments on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/murat_usenbai/0tpb8o5d/)

Comment: Can you provide your current code and a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've just edited post and added some experemental code. Thanks for your reply.